# Access files on a file server via IIS

Tags: .net, http, iis, file-transfer

In an application we are developing, I have access to a database table which gives me the path to some files that are available on a file server. This file server is accessible from the machine on which IIS is running. Is there a mechanism I can use to (on demand) copy a given file from the file server to the web server and make the file available for download by a given user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) protocol from a web-application to move the file over from a network mapped drive (from the file-server to the network server)  and then serve it up to the client.

You could just serve straight from the file server.

Here is some more [info](http://aspalliance.com/259).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to do a copy, as the client do not want to expose the file server directly.

Comment: You won't be exposing the file server, you will be exposing your web-server.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I will read up on how to use the SMB protocol.

Comment: You don't need to read up on the details of smb really, its a normal windows file share. Just map the file-server on the web-server as a local drive.